# How do i check if mail body contains a Password and extract from email body?

Tags: vb.net, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-activity

1. I was trying to do a for each activity, for each mail check if there is regular expression in mailbody then I want to if there is this regular expression in mail body
   After checking I want to save the file path of attachment in that email and the password to an excel (Password and path.xlsx)
2. I was wondering also if I can Open or UnProtect the password protected excel files sent as attachement in the email using the excel (Password and path.xlsx) to process the files inside.

[image]